# Write xmlns element with attributes

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlwriter

I'm using XmlWriter to generate an XML file. I am trying to replicate an old XML file and I want to create an entry that will look like;

```
<Return xmlns="http://address/here" appName="Data Return - Collection Tool" appVer="1.1.0">
```

My code is as follows:

```
        writer.WriteStartElement("Return", "http://address/here")
        writer.WriteAttributeString("appName", "Data Return - Collection Tool")
        writer.WriteAttributeString("appVer", "1.1.0")
```

This is generating the attributes in the wrong order ie.

```
<Return appName="Data Return - Collection Tool" appVer="1.1.0" xmlns="http://address/here">
```

How can i get these to appear in the order i want.
Any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XmlWriter` allow you to write the xmlns attribute when you want if the value is the same than the one specified in `WriteStartElement` :

```
void Main()
{
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Return", "http://address/here");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://address/here");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("appName", "Data Return - Collection Tool");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("appVer", "1.1.0");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString());
}
```

Output :

```
<Return xmlns="http://address/here" appName="Data Return - Collection Tool" appVer="1.1.0" />
```

Comment: A bit belated but thank-you @VirtualBlackFox. It worked - many thanks for your response.