# Insert or update XMLRoot Element dynamically

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have class with XMLRoot and one XMLElement on array. Based on client, when i serialize my class i have to change XMLRoot and XMLElement. Is there a way to change it dynamically

```
[XmlRoot("sample")]
public class MyData
{
    private ArrayList map;

    public MyData()
    {
        map = new ArrayList();
    }

    [XmlElement("url")]
    public Location[] Locations
    {
        get
        {
            Location[] items = new Location[map.Count];
            map.CopyTo(items);
            return items;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;
            Location[] items = (Location[])value;
            map.Clear();
            foreach (Location item in items)
                map.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public int Add(Location item)
    {
        return map.Add(item);
    }
}
```

As you can see, my root is "sample", based on client it can be "sample" or "reserved". XMLElement is "url" and based on client it can be "url" or "dataitem"

I'm serializing using XMLSerializer

```
// My condition needs to be here to determine which 
// root and xmlelement should use
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
var oString = new StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding.UTF8);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MSDN-Overrides on XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65k4wece(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can supply Overrides via the constructor - best read the doku.

**Example:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Location
{
    public string L;
}

[XmlRoot("sample")]
public class MyData
{
    public MyData()
    {
        map = new ArrayList();
    }

    [XmlElement("url")]
    public Location[] Locations
    {
        get
        {
            Location[] items = new Location[map.Count];
            map.CopyTo(items);
            return items;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;
            Location[] items = (Location[])value;
            map.Clear();
            foreach (Location item in items)
                map.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public int Add(Location item)
    {
        return map.Add(item);
    }

    private ArrayList map;
}

internal class Program
{
```

Xml Print To Screen:

```
    private static void DoSerialize(MyData m, XmlSerializer xs)
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

        var sww = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww, settings);
        xs.Serialize(writer, m);
        Console.WriteLine(sww.ToString().Replace("><", ">\r\n<"));
    }
```

Usage of overloaded Constructor:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        // testdata
        MyData m = new MyData 
        { 
            Locations = new Location[2] 
            { 
                new Location { L = "L1" }, 
                new Location { L = "L2" } 
            } 
        };

        // simple Serializer
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));

        DoSerialize(m, xs);
        Console.WriteLine();


        var xs2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData), XmlAttributeOverride(),
                     new Type[] { typeof(Location[]) }, RootOverride(), "");

        DoSerialize(m, xs2);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // override the root node
    private static XmlRootAttribute RootOverride() => new XmlRootAttribute("OtherName");

    // override your Languages property
    private static XmlAttributeOverrides XmlAttributeOverride()
    {
        var attrs = new XmlAttributes();
        attrs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute("Location"));

        var o = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        o.Add(typeof(MyData), "Locations", attrs);
        return o;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<sample xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://
www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <url>
    <L>L1</L>
  </url>
  <url>
    <L>L2</L>
  </url>
</sample>

<OtherName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http
://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Location>
    <L>L1</L>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <L>L2</L>
  </Location>
</OtherName>
```

Comment: It is working almost as per your solution. Only thing which i have issue now is i am getting xmlns declaration at <url> or <Location> level which i don't want

Comment: create a new SO question and provide details. I am happy about an upvote or accepted answer.

Comment: i'm getting <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <url xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <loc>https://www.domaincom/url.html</loc>
    <changefreq>always</changefreq>
    <lastmod>2017-09-11T04:50:27Z</lastmod>
  </url>
   </urlset>

Comment: Post your new code inside a new question. Post the data. Post the desired outcome. Comments aren't good for this. My guess would be you have to fiddle with the options of the XmlWriterSettings.

Comment: MAybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077265/write-xmlns-element-with-attributes  or this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.110).aspx